# Closed-loop function. Need help to check if my answer is correct

Tags: system

[image]

My answer:

Closed loop function formula can be found using (forward path / 1 + return path)

so Gr(s) = [(A+D(s))B] / (1 + [(A+D(s))B]) = heading angle / desired angle (correct or wrong?)

As for Gd(s) = B / (1 + (B + desired angle)A) = heading angle / D(s) ( correct or wrong ?)

How do I determine the order of the control system given that A = kp + kd s + ki/s and B = 1 /s^2 - alpha

This diagram can be found https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIa4M.png

Answer (score 0):

Yes - as mentioned by jp314, the denominator N(s) always is **N(s)=(1-loop gain)** and the (negative) loop gain is (-Forward*Return).

More than that, please note that for the transfer function GD(s) the "desired angle" input must be set to zero. Hence, we simply have **GD(s)=B/(1+AB).**

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a closed-loop TF with respect to a specific input, you must assume that all other inputs are zero. Thus, for \$\small\frac{\theta(s)}{\theta_r(s)}\$, take \$\small D(s)=0\$; for \$\small\frac{\theta(s)}{D(s)}\$, take \$\small \theta_r(s)=0\$.

The closed-loop TF for a negative feedback loop is: \$\small\frac{G(s)}{1+G(s)H(s)}\$, where \$\small G(s)\$ is the forward path, and \$\small H(s)\$ is the feedback path.

Note that there must be a minus sign (or odd number of minus signs) somewhere in the feedback path to make it negative feedback.

Identifying the feedback path is sometimes awkward - it's the path that goes from the output signal to the comparator that carries the input signal of interest. The geometry of the block diagram is irrelevant. For example, the feedback path for the \$\small\frac{\theta(s)}{D(s)}\$ CLTF is: \$\small A\$

In answer to your second question, the order of the TF is the highest power of \$\small s\$ in the TF denominator.

Comment: I see. So to find θ(s)/θr(s) , D(s) = 0 , so the transfer function is (AB) / (1+AB). As for θ(s)/D(s) , θr(s)=0 , thus , the transfer function is B / (1-AB). Am i correct?

Comment: Not exactly. Your 1st TF is correct. For your 2nd TF, the 'minus' should be 'plus'. Just apply the rule \$\small \frac{G}{1+GH}\$, there's always a + in the denominator for a negative feedback system.

Comment: But when θr(s) = 0 , the feedback to D(s) is positive.

Comment: What I mean is this http://postimg.org/image/4f4rn61bp/

Comment: KLDC, the feedback is still negative because the minus sign is still active - even if the "desired angle" input is zero.

Comment: I see. So it doesn't matter if the feedback sign (positive or negative) as shown in the link I provide. The feedback is always negative and hence it will always be 1 + GH on the denominator ?

Comment: Please ignore the previous comment. Is it because of this negative sign in the feedback which is why Gd(s)=  B / (1 +AB) I see. http://postimg.org/image/i2h0z3vzf/

Comment: First, establish whether the loop in question is negative feedback. If it is, then the TF will always be of the form G/(1+GH). Incidentally, what we're doing when considering a single input and turning all others to zero is using superposition (as in circuit analysis with several sources). The output is the sum of the contributions from all the inputs, taken one-by-one. But, of course, this requires a linear system, which is a pre-requisite for applying a TF.

Comment: Some people find it confusing if there is a plus or minus sign in the denominator. However, it very simple: The denominator always is D(s)=(1-loop gain). Because the loop gain for negative feedback always is negative (the loop gain must include the sign inversion anywhere within the loop), we have D(s)=(1+AB) when A and B are the transfer functions of the forward and the feedback path, respectively. The loop gain is LG=-A*B.

Comment: @LvW, the problem is that loop gain is often expressed in dB

Comment: @Chu, yes - I know. However, in the formula for closed-loop gain it MUST appear as an absolute value (with correct sign). It was my only intention to clarify, why sometimes there is a minus sign in the denominator (because the loop gain for negative feedback ALWAYS have a negative sign).

Comment: @LvW, ...'MUST'; who says so? Depends which book you read. It's just semantics.

Comment: @Chu, semantics? Show me the closed-loop gain formula where the loop gain appears in dB. Can you?

Comment: @LvW, I said '... the loop gain is often expressed in dB...', no mention of closed-loop gain. In any case, I have no intention of being drawn into another bad-tempered exchange with you. End of.

Comment: Bad-tempered? Why? (Your statement: "The problem is that loop gain is often expressed in dB"). Where do you see any problem? Its a simple and factual question, is it not?